# Show value selected into search suggestion in multiple select2 input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I have a `select2` multiple value like below

```
<select class="form-control" name="name" multiple="multiple" id="name"></select>
```

Right now, If the user want to add 10 name simultaneously, so user typed `name` one by one , if `name` value typed in `number 8` is same with their `name` typed in `number 3` before it will not enter to `select2` val.

To handle this, I tried to show value that already typed into, like search suggestion or search box like image below

[image: select2]

Do you know how to do that ? because right now, the search suggestion is not showing in my `select2` input

Here's the code

```
 $("#name").select2({
    tags: true
});
```

Thank you

Comment: If I understand the question this is the normal behaviour of [select2 multiselect](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage#multi-select-boxes-pillbox)

Comment: Hi @MoshFeu, so can I add the search box like the example image ?

Comment: You get it out of the box with select2..